# How will we come to know that the data are evenly distributed across cluster in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

How will we come to know that the data are evenly distributed across cluster in Spark

Answer (score 1):

You can check the same in Spark Web UI where you can see how many tasks are getting created and how are they executing in different nodes. You can also check whether your executors are getting skewed and taking time to write. You can also work on  a real time example , take a file of 15 GB and process the file in your 4 node 16 GB 4 core machines. After reading do a re-partition of 10 and do some simple aggregation and  write to some other directory. You will able to see how parallel tasks are getting create and executing in Task Nodes.